# Returning Two Pointers to Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am having a bunch of problems with pointers and dynamic arrays here.
I have a function that I call, that does a bunch a stuff, like removing an ellement from the dynamic array , which leads me to reallocating memory to one of those dynamic arrays. The problem is I call functions within functions, and I can't return all my values properly to the Main.
Since I can't return 2 values, how can I do this?

```
structure1* register(structure1 *registerArray,structure2 *waitingList, int counter){
    //Bunch of code in here
    registerArray = realloc(inspecao, (counter)+1);
    waitingList = eliminate(waitingList, 5, counter); //Doesn't matter what it does really

    return registerArray;
}


structure1* eliminate(structure1 *arrayToEliminateFrom, int positionToEliminate, int *counter){

    //The code for this doesn't matter
    //All I do is eliminate an ellement and reallocate it
    arrayToEliminateFrom = realloc(arrayToEliminateFrom, (*counter-1)*sizeof(structure1))
    return arrayToEliminateFrom;
}
```

As you can see , I don't know how to return the pointer to the waitingList dynamic array to the Main. How can I do this? 
I have searched everywhere.
Help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but any "return n values" issue can be solved by passing a pointer to n variables to be written to.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I don't know how to have a pointer to pointer.

Comment: I'm going to provide an answer to your real problem, but `register` is actually an old C _keyword_ attribute like `extern` or `static`.  Not used much these days, but still illegal as a symbol, so just rename it (e.g. registerx or xregister or register_array)

Comment: Craig , I changed the name of the function to register while I was writing on stackoverflow.. since the name of the function is in Portuguese and it could be confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here are two ways to do it.

The first is, based upon your comment, what you think your instructor would want:

```
void
xregister(structure1 **registerArray, int *arrayCount,
    structure1 **waitingList, int *waitCount)
{

    // Bunch of code in here

    *arrayCount += 1;
    *registerArray = realloc(inspecao, *arrayCount * sizeof(structure1));

    // Doesn't matter what it does really
    eliminate(waitingList, 5, waitCount)
}

void
eliminate(structure1 **arrayToEliminateFrom, int positionToEliminate,
int *count)
{

    // The code for this doesn't matter

    *count -= 1;

    // All I do is eliminate an ellement and reallocate it
    *arrayToEliminateFrom = realloc(*arrayToEliminateFrom,
        *count * sizeof(structure1))
}
```

Here is what Roberto and I were suggesting.  Actually, mine's a general variable length array approach that can be fully generalized with some slight field changes.  In a way, since you're already using a struct, I can't see why your instructor would object to this as it's a standard way to do it.  Less cumbersome and cleaner.

```
struct vector {
    int vec_count;
    structure1 *vec_base;
};

void
xregister(vector *registerArray,vector *waitingList)
{

    // Bunch of code in here

    registerArray->vec_count += 1;
    registerArray->vec_base = realloc(registerArray->vec_base,
        registerArray->vec_count * sizeof(structure1));

    // Doesn't matter what it does really
    eliminate(waitingList, 5)
}

void
eliminate(vector *arrayToEliminateFrom, int positionToEliminate)
{

    // The code for this doesn't matter

    arrayToEliminateFrom->vec_count -= 1;

    // All I do is eliminate an ellement and reallocate it
    arrayToEliminateFrom->vec_base = realloc(arrayToEliminateFrom->vec_base,
        arrayToEliminateFrom->vec_count * sizeof(structure1))
}
```

Here's an even more compact way:

```
struct vector {
    int vec_count;
    structure1 *vec_base;
};

void
vecgrow(vector *vec,int inc)
{

    vec->vec_count += inc;
    vec->vec_base = realloc(vec->vec_base,vec->vec_count * sizeof(structure1));
}

void
xregister(vector *registerArray,vector *waitingList)
{

    // Bunch of code in here

    vecgrow(registerArray,1);

    // Doesn't matter what it does really
    eliminate(waitingList, 5)
}

void
eliminate(vector *arrayToEliminateFrom, int positionToEliminate)
{

    // The code for this doesn't matter

    vecgrow(arrayToEliminateFrom,-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to do an higher structure that contains both pointers and pass and return that structure beetween your functions, because function can return only one object/structure, but your structure/object can contain more objects/structures

Comment: You've got the right idea [I was going to suggest the same].  It might be helpful to flesh this out for OP by recoding his stuff.  (e.g.) With the extra struct, most funcs can now return void and [need] take only one argument. This might not be apparent to OP

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I don't think that my teachers want me to do that. Isn't there someway in which I can directly edit the pointer in the main?

Comment: I thought that by passing the pointer of the dynamic array to the function it would change automatically. But it seems to be making a copy, and not changing the original. How do I pass by reference, or pointer to pointer?